# Why does SRS not recognize the audio format correctly in an RTMP stream?

Tags: audio, simple-realtime-server

SRS did not recognize the audio format correctly, the pushed RTMP stream is mono, but it is displayed as stereo on the webpage.

Using ffmpeg (version 4.4) to re-encode and forward an RTMP stream. The original stream is in speex format, mono, and 16000 Hz. The ffmpeg command is as follows

`ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/livestream -vn -ac 1 -ar 22050 -c:a libfdk_aac -f flv rtmp://IP/live/livestream`

test SRS version

```
v-4.0.268
v-4.0.251
```

ffmpeg returns as follows

```
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
  ...

  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 3046.899000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 65 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
  ...
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 48 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libfdk_aac
```

ffprob info as follows

```
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 10.867000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, 47 kb/s
```

SRS website recognize

```
Recv: 0.00Kbps
Send: 0.00Kbps
Audio: AAC/22050/Stereo/LC
```

I set OBS to mono and directly pushed the stream, but with FFMPEG, it is displayed as follows on the webpage

```
Recv: 0.00Kbps
Send: 0.00Kbps
Video: H264/Baseline/4/1920x1080
Audio: AAC/44100/Stereo/LC
```

ffprob info (rtmp)

```
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2625 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Data: none
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 65 kb/s
  Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 2560 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn
```

Comment: Should file an issue at https://github.com/ossrs/srs/issues

Comment: ok，I synchronized an issue on git，tks for your response